# Joining line data to points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

[image]

Assets:
Green point layer
Blue point layer (with alphabetical FID attribute)
Red line layer (with numerical FID Attribute)
Blue line layer

Goal:
Join red line FID attribute to Blue point in order away from Green point

Blue Point layer attributes

[A][2]
B|1
[C][5]
[D][6]
[E][3]
[F][7]
[G][8]

How can this be done?

Comment: You had a tag for PyQGIS but did not include a code attempt or mention it in your question body so I removed it.

Comment: More details please about what you're trying to do. Don't be afraid to over-explain.